# I cannot "add" additional column to the OPENED Email Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to pull contacts who opened specific email. I'm beginner so I'm using the query i found in documentation that works but on top of that query I would like to add additional column.

Here's the query:

```
Select
j.JobID,
j.EmailName,
j.DeliveredTime as SendTime,
o.EventDate as OpenTime,
s.EmailAddress,
s.SubscriberKey
from [_Job] j
join [_Open] o
on j.JobID = o.JobID
join [_Subscribers] s
on o.SubscriberID = s.SubscriberID
where
o.IsUnique = 1 and
o.EventDate > dateadd(d,-7,getdate()) and
j.EmailID = 2069
```

I wanted just to ask for the column name in Select after EmailAddress and SubscriberKey but it doesn't work - it says that it's wrong column name:

```
Select
j.JobID,
j.EmailName,
j.DeliveredTime as SendTime,
o.EventDate as OpenTime,
s.EmailAddress,
s.SubscriberKey,
s.PurchaseDate
from [_Job] j
join [_Open] o
on j.JobID = o.JobID
join [_Subscribers] s
on o.SubscriberID = s.SubscriberID
where
o.IsUnique = 1 and
o.EventDate > dateadd(d,-7,getdate()) and
j.EmailID = 2069
```

Could you explain me how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to perform a query to get details on specific email opens, you query what’s called a [Data View](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5&language=da). In your example, there are three of these involved:

1. [Open](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5&language=da)
2. [Job](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_job.htm&type=5&language=da)
3. [Subscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5&language=da)

All of these above hold information which is related to the sends performed by marketing cloud. You can look into each of the links to see the lists of fields available in each of the views.

As purchase information is normally not collected natively by marketing cloud, it is also not available in any of the data views (you are trying to fetch it from Subscribers). Hence you can’t just add the field name to your query.

You might have the purchase information in a different data extension in marketing cloud, calling for another JOIN in your query. I would advise you to team up with someone more knowledgeable of your data model and SQL to combine these different data sources in order to produce the insights you are after.